# Cmake include path problem: How do I build library "A" without installing required lib "B" n /usr/local/include...?

Tags: cmake, makefile, include

I'm trying to build an open source library "A", which uses cmake.  I have the library
sources in a subdirectory, with my own top-level Makefile that invokes cmake and does
the make command.

The problem is that the library requires the specific version of another library "B"
to be installed. There is no debian package for this version, only an earlier version.
The earlier version is installed and cannot be removed.  I have the correct version
of library "B" built and installed into a local build tree.  I can generate the path
to the proper include files, but I can't install the other library onto /usr/local/...,
because, you know, reasons that are irrelevant to this problem...  I also can't remove
the earlier version of library "B".

I don't want to modify either source tree in any way, if I can avoid it at all.  I need to
be able to control the include path from my top-level Makefile via the cmake or make
invocations.

What seems to be happening is that when the library "A" source files are compiled they are
finding the includes from the old version of "B" in /usr/local/include, and the old version
is missing things that the library "A" needs.

I can't figure out how to get cmake to find and use the locally built include files from
library "B" before the ones in /usr/local.  I've tried using various settings, like
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH, CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and CMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE="ON" to get
it to use the path to the local library "B" include files, but nothing seems to work.

What I need to do is to specify an include file path that is searched before the normal
/usr/include and /usr/local/include directories.  Seems like a simple enough problem to
solve.

Is there a simple solution to this problem that involves only parameters to cmake or make?

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is normally a correct way for hint CMake about custom location of a library. If it doesn't work... then your situation probably differs from the common one. Please, add to the question post **more details** (code!) about the way how the library "A" finds the library "B" and links with it.